# I just want to bind simple shortcuts like linux in windows but autohotkey is too much for me

Tags: autohotkey

I want to bind some basic Linux shortcuts into Windows and when I looked for solutions people are saying AutoHotKey scripts are very useful.

But it's a whole language and I want some basic binding and when I looked into documentation I have to start from beginning tutorial which take too much time

So please can you just tell me code for which I also looked into internet but not found so much.

I want to bind below keys

`mod + q` => quit current window

`mod + enter` => open cmd

`mod + tab` => switch between windows ( like => alt + tab )

`mod + f` => toggle full screen ( like => F11 )

`mod + 1` => go to workspace 1

`mod + 2` => go to workspace 2

It's only 3 or 4 shortcuts I want to bind, and I don't want to waste too much time. How can I write a .ahk script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first and second bindings:

```
#q::WinClose, A  ;Close active window
#Return::run cmd ;Start Command Prompt
```

Assuming you meant "Virtual Desktop" when you said "workspace" in your third and fourth bindings, I recommend that you just use [this Windows 10 Desktop manager ahk script](https://github.com/jpginc/windows10DesktopManager). I've used it for a couple of years, and it works pretty nicely. If you wanted to implement it yourself, you would have to deal with a couple of dll calls that this script nicely implements as functions. I would recommend scrolling to the bottom of the linked GitHub page to see how to set it up.

Comment: Hey i want one more two bindings if you can help ` mod + tab ` ==> switch between windows , ` mod + f ` ==> make window full screen

Comment: You should really ask this as a separate question instead of unaccepting an answer that solved an existing question, and asking a new question in the comments of that answer. While I would be glad to help you solve these new requests, there are a couple of things that I would want to ask you to clarify about them. Asking for this clarification in these comments would be far less than ideal.